# EncodeURIComponent/DecodeURIComponent with characters like "é"

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, encode, urlencode

I have a web application, with some drop-down list.
One of these list have some parameters with an accent, such as : `"Bonjour/COUCOU SPéCIALISTE/AB12345"`

So when I select it and I made the research I end up with the following url:

```
abcdefgh.com/someFunction?way=null&motive=bonjour%2Fcoucou+spécialiste%2FAB12345
```

In my function, I have:

```
var somethingPercentage = getSomethingPercentage(
    decodeURIComponent(queryParams.way),
    decodeURIComponent(queryParams.motive)
);
```

And, in a config file, I have made the matching parameter like this:

```
"bonjour/coucou+spécialiste/ab12345": 0.01
```

In the result, I have a bad call.
But when I select some parameters with no accent, I don't have this problem and the result is the good.

The problem is the same if the parameter have some space.

Why is this behaviour happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just found.

I have just put

```
logger.info(decodeURIComponent(queryParams.motive));
```

after the following code :

```
var somethingPercentage = getSomethingPercentage(
decodeURIComponent(queryParams.way),
decodeURIComponent(queryParams.motive));
```

Now, i have find the necessary value to match.

It was not a problem of "é" but a problem of space in my case.